# How to create a blent-in navigation bar like the one on Apple Music artist page

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a navigation bar (everything above "top songs" in the screenshot) that looks like the one used in the artist pages in the Apple Music app. On the iPhone X, the cover photo should blend into the notch area (i.e. outside the safe area). I also want to be able to add UI elements such as UILabels into the navigation bar.

Screenshot:
https://i2.wp.com/9to5mac.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2018/06/apple-music-artist-update.jpg

So far, I've tried using a UITableViewController. I set the content inset parameter of the tableview to be "Never", which seems to do the job. However, when dragging downward when the table view is already at the top cell, the background of the UITableView is revealed. When dragging the table downward, the background image of the first cell should be stretched instead of moving with the cell content.

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow isn’t the place to ask a general, “How do I do something?” type question. It is specifically for questions about problems you might be having with your code. Try to implement a solution and if you hit problems show your code and any errors. Please don’t simply ask how to do something, this isn’t the place

Comment: Hey Magnas I did describe the problem with the UITableViewController in my question. I’m just tying to figure out why, when stretched, the content in the top cell wouldn’t stretch with the table view.

Comment: That's my point, StackOverflow is for code. If you have code you'd like help with, please post it. None code specific questions, like yours, belong elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution:

First, open storyboard, drag a UIView to the top of "prototype cell".
Then, define the following global var in the view controller file:

```
var headerView: UIView!
var HEADER_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 400
```

To update the header view (i.e. stretch) when scrolled, call the following func in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method:

```
func updateTableHeader() 
{
    var headerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -HEADER_HEIGHT, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: HEADER_HEIGHT)
    if tableView.contentOffset.y < -HEADER_HEIGHT
    {
        headerFrame.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
        headerFrame.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y
    }
    headerView.frame = headerFrame
}
```

Also, in `viewDidLoad`, the headerView should be configured using the following method:

```
func setupHeaderview()
{
    headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    tableView.addSubview(headerView)
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: HEADER_HEIGHT, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -HEADER_HEIGHT)
    updateTableHeader()
}
```